# How do I mock a class member, or force a constructor to return a mock?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am currently using Moq, but could use another framework if it's easier.

I want to test a class looking like this:

```
using System.Threading;
public class Foo
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));

    public static void ThreadProc()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }
    }

    public Foo()
    {

    }

    public virtual void Interrupt()
    {
        if (thread.IsAlive)
        {
            thread.Interrupt();
        }
    }

}
```

Now I want to test the Intertupt method. In order to do so I want to Mock the thread member in order to verify that the Intetrupt method is hit depending of the IsAlive value.

How can I mock it ?

PS: This is not my real code, this is simply an example as I cannot post my real code. However the issue I have is the same, I need to have a class constructor to return an object when called.

Comment: `public Foo(IThread thread)` Then write `ThreadWrapper` that implements `IThread` and wraps thread. Mock it as needed.

Comment: In order to mock dependencies easily, use interfaces and pass dependencies in constructors.

Comment: I have no access to the class that actually instantiate the object, the Thread is actually a serialized field in this kind of case, how should I proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

An admittedly ugly way of getting around this is to change the protection level of `thread` from `private` to `protected`, then have the testing class inherit from the class under test. Based on the example code you've provided, it would look something like this:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    [SerializeField]
    protected Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
    ...
}

public class FooUnitTests: Foo {
  private readonly Mock<Thread> threadMock = new Mock<Thread>();

  [TestMethod]
  public void Interrupt_ThreadIsAlive_CallsThreadInterrupt() {
    threadMock.SetUp(m => m.IsAlive).Returns(true);
    threadMock.SetUp(m => m.Interrupt()).Verifiable();

    Interrupt();

    threadMock.VerifyAll();
  }

  public FooUnitTests {
    thread = threadMock.Object;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I can do that, but it is an interesting hack.
I could maybe do it with reflexivity too.
Actually, I am working with Unity, and found some very interesting links about dependency injections with Unity, so I am going to have a look to them too.